# How to install .NET Framework 3.0 on Windows XP Embedded SP3

Tags: windows-xp, installation, .net-framework

How to install .NET Framework 3.0 on Windows XP Embedded SP3 without re-building the installation image?

I have read that one of the options is to install the "Update Rollup 1.0 for Windows XP Embedded" from Microsoft but it seems like SP3 should already contain all the necessary dependencies.

Should mention that if attempted to install currently, the process stops with error message 1603, indicating that "Windows Communication Foundation did not install".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this method and it seems to be the only one that actually works:

Perform actions in the following order:

1. Use [.Net Framework Cleanup Tool](https://web.archive.org/web/20160301085724/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx) to make your system .NET free
2. Install .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 1
3. Install .NET Framework 3.0 (the error should stop now)
4. Install .NET Framework 3.0 Service Pack 1
5. Install .NET Framework 3.5
6. Install .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20161018131224/http://asoit.com/installing-net-3-5-on-windows-xp/)

Comment: I don't mind that you took (back) the check-mark, but link-only  answers are a no-no.  Please include pertinent information directly in your answer and link the web page as a source.

Comment: @techie007 I've corrected based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft's article: "[Installing Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 on Windows XP Embedded Service Pack 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417255%28v=winembedded.5%29.aspx)" -- I don't think you can, at least not unless you happened to have built the image previously with all required components needed for installing .NET.

> To include the .NET Framework 3.0 in Windows XP Embedded Service Pack
>   2 systems, first construct a run-time image that is compatible with
>   .NET Framework 3.0. Next, run the .NET Framework 3.0 desktop
>   installation package for Windows XP Professional on that image after
>   First Boot Agent (FBA) is finished.

And under "[Running the .NET Framework 3.0 Desktop Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417255%28v=winembedded.5%29.aspx#RunningtheNETFramework30DesktopInstaller)":

> After building the Windows XP Embedded Service Pack 2 run-time image
>   with the new .NET Framework 3.0 macro component and after FBA has
>   finished, download and run the .NET Framework 3.0 desktop installer.

Prerequisite components ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417255%28v=winembedded.5%29.aspx#ComponentsRequiredforNETFramework30Installation)):

- Accessibility Core
- Active Directory Service Interface (ADSI) Core
- Base Performance Counters
- COM+ Services
- Common Control Libraries Version 5
- Common File Dialogs
- Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MSDTC)
- Down-level Shell Compat
- GDI+ XP
- HTML Help Engine
- Internet Explorer
- Local Security Authority Subsystem (LSASS)
- Message Queuing (MSMQ) Core
- Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)
- Microsoft Management Console (MMC)
- Microsoft Visual C++ Run Time
- Microsoft-Windows-HTTP
- Ole Automation
- OLE Dialog Interfaces
- Performance Counter Configuration
- Performance Data Helper
- Primitive: Cabinet
- Primitive: Crypt32
- Primitive: CryptUI
- Primitive: Dbgeng
- Primitive: Dbghelp
- Primitive: Imagehlp
- Primitive: Imm32
- Primitive: Mpr
- Primitive: Msi
- Primitive: Msimg32
- Primitive: Mswsock
- Primitive: Netapi32
- Primitive: Ntdll
- Primitive: Ole32
- Primitive: Oleaut32
- Primitive: Psapi
- Primitive: Secur32
- Primitive: Security
- Primitive: Setupapi
- Primitive: Shell32
- Primitive: Shlwapi
- Primitive: Userenv
- Primitive: uxtheme
- Primitive: Version
- Primitive: Winmm
- Primitive: Winspool
- Primitive: Wintrust
- Primitive: Ws2_32
- Primitive: Wsock32
- Primitive: Wtsapi32
- Registry Editor
- Remote Registry Service
- Rich Edit Control Version 3.0
- RPC Local Support
- System Restore Core
- Urlmon Library
- Video For Windows Core
- Windows API – Advanced
- Windows API – GDI
- Windows API – Kernel
- Windows API – User
- Windows Installer Service
- Windows Logon
- Wininet Library
- WMI Core
- WMI Tools
- WMI Win32 Provider